# What is the difference between "continue to" and "continue the"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Hello I have a student that asked me this question.

I mentioned that the "continue to" + verb focuses on the verb but "continue the" focuses on the noun phrase to follow.  Is that correct?

Comment: Please provide context. Give at least one complete sentence for each use.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there's no meaningful context

Answer (score 0):

Both are very similar. When you say "continue to," that can mean different things. You can put an infinitive after it, and "continue" will act as a transitive verb. "I continued to mow the lawn."

But you can also use "continue to" as an intransitive verb, where you might say something like this: "Many of the traditions continue to this day."

For "continue the," it will usually just be used as a transitive verb as well, just with a noun after it. "I will continue the process."

Both of them are just ways to use the verb "continue." I guess you can say that a difference between them is that "continue the" will be transitive, and "continue to" will be transitive or intransitive. If you say "continue the" it will usually be followed by a noun phrase, but saying "continue to" relates to verbs is ambiguous.

Comment: I think this answer is misleading and unhelpful. Neither _continue to_ nor _continue the_ is a  syntactic component: they are just sequences of words. _Continue_ can be a transitive verb, in which case it is followed by a noun phrase (which might happen to start with _the_) or a non-finite clause (which could be an infinitival clause which starts with _to_). When it is an intransitive verb it can take a prepositional phrase as a complement, often starting with _to_.